# Installing npm modules makes flex crash with type errors

Tags: react-native

I'm attempting to use a component in my React Native project, specifically this one:
https://github.com/lucholaf/react-native-grid-view

I run `npm install react-native-grid-view` in the project's directory, but as soon as I do that, after building I get: 
[image]
Is the problem that I'm running `npm install` in the wrong location?  I've tried other directories, but then React doesn't see the modules and says "unknown module".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the component was pointing to an older version of React Native, 0.3.4.  Manually updated to 0.4 and it worked.